# Creating a spiral in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a bar spiral in d3 and I'm using this resource: http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/222043d93a41d48b58d2bfa1e3d4f708
I'm not getting an error, but also I'm just getting a blank page no chart at all. Any guidance on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated. Also the console.table isn't showing data, even though initially it did.

```
// reading in the data 
const dataset = d3.csv("/Journalists_Death.csv").then(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0]);
  });

//creating spiral chart
var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    start = 0,
    end = 2.25,
    numSpirals = 4;

var theta = function(r) {
    return numSpirals * Math.PI * r;
};

var r = d3.min([width, height]) / 2 - 40;
var radius = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([start, end])
    .range([40, r]);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("tranform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ","+ height / 2 +")");

// create the spiral, borrowed from http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3543186
var points = d3.range(start, end + 0.001, (end = start) / 1000);

var spiral = d3.radialLine()
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
    .angle(theta)
    .radius(radius);

var path = svg.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("id", "spiral")
    .attr("d", spiral)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue");

//fudge some data, 2 years of data starting today
var spiralLength = path.node().getTotalLength(),
    N = 730,
    barWidth = (spiralLength / N) - 1;
year = d => d.year
Total = d => d.Total

//here's our time scale that'll run along the spiral
var timeScale = d3.scaleTime() //line 52
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d){
        return d.year;
    }))
    .range([0, spiralLength]);

//yScale for the bar height
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){
        return d.Total
    })])
    .range([0, (r/numSpirals) - 30]);

//append our rects
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        //placement calculations
        var linePer = timeScale(d.year),
            posOnLine = path.node().getPointAtLength(linePer),
            angleOnLine = path.node().getPointAtLength(linePer - barWidth);

            d.linePer = linePer; // % of distance are on the spiral
            d.x = posOnLine.x; // x position on the spiral
            d.y = posOnLine.y; // y on position on the spiral
            d.a = (Math.atan2(angleOnLine.y, angleOnLine.x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
            
            return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d){
        return barWidth;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d){
        return yScale(d.Total);
    })
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke", "none")
    .attr("transform", function(d){
        return "rotate(" + d.a + "," + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
```

Comment: Please turn your code into a runnable [mre], using stack snippets or JSFiddle/CodePen. If you host your data online, like on GitHub, or use some sample data that looks like it, that would help as well. This will help you get better answers

Comment: What do you see when you log your dataset? You are not using d3.csv correctly, it should be of the form (for v4) `d3.csv('path', function(error, data) { /* use data here */ })`

Comment: @AndrewReid thank you so i've got the data reading in correctly now and it shows when I do a console.log. However, still no chart I get an error that: d3.v6.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: t is not iterable
    at Object.p [as extent] (d3.v6.min.js:2)
    at chart.js:53

Comment: Can you update your question with your updated code and mark which line is line 53?

Comment: Hi @AndrewReid I've edited and marked when line 52 is